# remove class when radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a button book if the radio is checked all the class disabled in the button book will be remove and if the one only checked then the button book remains disabled.

I've tried to make its function but not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var departInput = $('#flightResultOneway input:radio');
  var returnInput = $('#flightResultReturn input:radio');

  $(departInput).click(function() {
    $('#flightResultOneway input:not(:checked)').parent().addClass('hide');
    $('#flightResultOneway input:checked').parent().removeClass('hide');
  });

  $(returnInput).click(function() {
    $('#flightResultReturn input:not(:checked)').parent().addClass('hide');
    $('#flightResultReturn input:checked').parent().removeClass('hide');
  });
});

// BUTTON BOOK
if($('#flightResultOneway input:checked')){
 $('#book').removeClass('disabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="flightResultOneway" class="list-result">
<h1>Depart</h1>
  <div class="result-list">
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="depart">lion
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="depart">citi
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="flightResultReturn" class="list-result">
<h1>Return</h1>
  <div class="result-list">
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="return">citi
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="return">lion
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="next-book">
  <a href="#" id="book" class="btn btn-primary disabled">book</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please describe your problem more specifically so we can get the problem.

Comment: between check your fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5fgao0cb/4/)

Comment: i want to if radio not checked button book disabled. when checked all button book enable. thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want...

```
$(document).on("change", "input[type='radio']", function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
    $("#book").attr("disabled", false);
        if($(this).is(":checked") === false){
            $("#book").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    }); 
});
```

And your html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="flightResultOneway" class="list-result">
<h1>Depart</h1>
  <div class="result-list">
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="depart">lion
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="depart">citi
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="flightResultReturn" class="list-result">
<h1>Return</h1>
  <div class="result-list">
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="return">citi
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <input type="radio" name="return">lion
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="next-book">
  <a href="#" id="book" class="btn btn-primary disabled">book</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i'm trying your code but not work https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/Lt2mmaqz/1/